# Decimal format conversion from one locale to another locale(en_US) in Apex Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a decimal in a string format in a locale that is not 'en_US'. I would like to convert it to a decimal in 'en_US' locale.

Eg: "123.345.123,45" -> "123345123.45" or "123,345,123.45"

"123 345,45" -> "123345.45" or "123,345.45"

"123.345" -> "123345" or "123,345"